# After editing a post, "x% accept rate" disappears

Tags: bug, status-completed, accept-rate, inline-editor

When you edit a post (inline editing) and click `Save Edits`, the text `x% accept rate` (where `x` is some percentage) below the poster's user card in the bottom right-hand corner disappears. I think this should stay as there is no real reason for removing it after an edit.

Please let me know if this is the expected behaviour and if not, whether it can be fixed.

Comment: Reproduced. How peculiar. Can't really say that it's necessary to have the accept rate visible post-edit, but at the same time, it's curious why it would be removed in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for finding this - a fix will be pushed this evening.